# Unable to set a Static IP Address in elementary os

Tags: settings

How do i set a static IP address? 
unable to find documentation on using the gui or terminal. It would probably be easier if i knew what fork of Linux this was developed from.

Answer (score 1):

Elementary was originally based on Ubuntu, which was originally based on Debian.

You can set a static IP via the Network settings GUI.

1. Click Applications menu.
2. Click System Settings from the menu.
3. Click Network from the settings app.
4. Select your network connection in left-hand sidebar.
5. Click Advanced Settings in the lower-right corner.
6. Click the IPv4 settings tab.
7. Select Manual as the configuration method.
8. Set your IP.
9. Repeat on the IPv6 tab if needed.
10. Click Save.